# Removing Rokanthemes from Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to remove the Rokanthemes theme from my Magento 2 store.
I have tried deleting all the folders, but this made my "Categories" page freak out. It gives me the following error message when trying to get to categories:

***"Class "Rokanthemes\Categorytab\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Thumbnailimage" does not exist"***

I have tried also getting rid of anything named '%rokan%' in the database, and tried flushing and regenerating all the files.

If anyone has more advice, or has some commands that need to be run, that would be a huge help.

We are using another theme, and Rokanthemes had to be deleted because of conflicts in CSS and layout. So leaving it in unused also isn't a valid option.

Rokanthemes is also not available in admin panel like it was before, and all functionality is gone. This just seems to be some code left behind in files without Rokan in their name, and I can't figure out where it is or where to look.
The error log contains the following message as well:

***#40 main{ "report_id":"83893850246dd269da358cd0501ea429bfa43b7fd3c3459b693815ca7c26af08","exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class "Rokanthemes\Categorytab\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Thumbnailimage" does not exist at /home///vendor//framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:34)"} []***

*Obscured some text for privacy reasons*

ANY help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a custom category attribute created by Rokanthemes needs to be removed. This attribute is associated with a backend model that no longer exists due to the deletion of the theme files.

To identify any custom attributes created by the theme, you can utilize the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE backend_model LIKE '%Rokanthemes%';
```

Once you have confirmed you do not need the attributes or their data, you can delete them using:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE backend_model LIKE '%Rokanthemes%';
```